# WP_Query won't retrieve raw HTML?

Tags: wp-query

I have a WordPress page named Services where the content is custom HTML (added in the Text tab in TinyMCE). I'm trying to use `WP_Query` on the splash page to pull the Services content and display it inside a `DIV`. What I'm getting however is plain text. It looks like `WP_Query` is parsing the HTML and then displaying what is left. The URL is not public, but here is my PHP recommended by the theme tech support (ElegantThemes/Vertex) ...

```
<section class="home-block et-odd">
<div class="container">

<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'page_id=4' ); ?>
<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();  ?>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endwhile;?>

</div> <!-- .container -->
</section>
```

Comment: Did you try `the_content()` instead of `the_excerpt()` ?

Comment: First, `the_content()` worked beautifully. The tut I was looking at only talked about how to use `the_excerpt()` and not the other options. I also found info explaining that `WP_Query` is an 'object' etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WP_Query` object contains **FULL** content of posts/pages retrieved from database. No HTML tags are being removed. Therefore, the following statement in your question:

> It looks like WP_Query is parsing the HTML and then displaying what is
>   left.

is not true.

If you use, in your code, `the_content()` instead of `the_excerpt()` function, you'll see that all original HTML tags are preserved.

It is important to understand how excerpts are being generated. What is being displayed by `the_excerpt()` function? This is the code:

```
echo apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', get_the_excerpt() );
```

`get_the_excerpt()` function is responsible for generation of the excerpt's text.

From Codex:

> Returns the excerpt of the post. This is either a user-supplied
>   excerpt, that is returned unchanged, or an automatically generated
>   word-counted trimmed-down version of the full post content.
>
> The auto-generated excerpts have all shortcodes and tags removed which
>   means it is just an unformatted string that would not see any
>   line-breaks in any form of output, since the actual line-breaks in the
>   raw text are also removed.

In your case, `the_excerpt()` function displays an auto-generated excerpt, with HTML tags removed. To change this behavior, you can use 'the_excerpt' filter to add HTML formatting, or fill page's **Excerpt** meta-box, with desired, HTML formatted text.

Comment: Frank your comments along with previous tip exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!